# Is using X-Real-IP as a way to check for localhost access safe?

Tags: http, nginx

I have an application listening on the port 5000 that can be accessed to the internet through nginx with this configuration:

```
upstream myapp {
    server 127.0.0.1:5000;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myapp;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
#...
}
```

Now, assuming the port 5000 can only be accessed directly from the localhost, I assume that all external communication is handled by nginx, I am assuming that all requests that the application receives which **do not have the X-Real-IP header** come from localhost.

Are these assumptions wrong? Could a person with no access to the machine still access the web application without auth? Am I missing something?

---

**Edit:** I think I may not be stating a clear question here. Probably a mix between my lack of knowledge and me thinking I am understanding something fundamentally wrong. So, I think you could sum up my doubts in answering this:

In this situation, can I assume that if a request to my web app does not have the "X-Real-IP" header then it's coming from localhost?

or the opposite:

Can I somehow forge a request that would make nginx not set the X-Real-IP header, given the configuration above?

Cheers!

Comment: You're always setting `X-Real-IP`, so any request going through Nginx will have that header.  The only way it wouldn't have the header would be to directly make a request through localhost:5000, and leave that header out.  With the current configuration that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already asuming that only localhost traffic can reach your web app on port 5000. Thus, checking any header you set in nginx is not the factor in deciding wether this is a request from localhost - all are, by definition.

If your question rather is

> can I assume that all that have the 'X-Real-IP' Header set come from 'nginx'"

the answer would be "no"; you can easily curl that on localhost.

Edit to reflect the edit in the question:

You can assume - with your presumptions - that every request on port 5000 comes from localhost, regardless of the headers.

As of now (i.e., to my knowledge, there is no exploit to allow that happening regardless of the configuration), if that configuration is *all* the configuration there is, there is no way to make nginx forward a request without setting the header.

Comment: My question is actually the opposite. I have tried to edit the question to reflect that accordingly. I'm starting to think I'm just worrying unnecessarily...

Comment: I edited the answer as well,@alfro. But this seems like an [xyproblem](http://xyproblem.info) tbh.